# Django view doesnt seems to have any request object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get request.user but even printing request doesn't works.But nothing is printing

view.py

```
def flower_add(request):
    print request
    print request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'xxxx'
        form = FlowerAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print "form is is_valid"
            form.save()
        context= {'form':FlowerAddForm()}
        return render(request, 'farmer/flower_add.html',context)
    else:
        form = FlowerAddForm()

    return render(request, 'farmer/flower_add.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Comment: Where are you hoping to see the output?

Comment: Does the code really look like what you've posted? Be aware that Python cares about indentation.

Comment: Sorry all it my mistake! i wrote two view with same name. Thanks all problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Your view here may be working but you likely won't get any output to the console using print in the manner you are using it.

Try calling print() as a function with request explicitly passed.

Also, print() is ideal for string objects (as well as int, etc) but no so much for more complex types such as dictionaries, lists and other structured objects.
Try using pprint() instead:

```
pprint(request)
print(request.method)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: Sorry all it my mistake! i wrote two view with same name. Thanks all problem is solved!